# Unable to create a apex test class for readonlyfieldmap apex code

Tags: apex

Following is the apex code for which i am unable to create test class for readonlyfieldmap. Please help me.

```
public void doQuery(String recId){

        String query = 'SELECT Id, RecordType.Name ' + formQuery() + ' FROM Test_Tool__c WHERE ID =:recId';       

        edaoTest = new Test_Tool__c();
        edaoTest = Database.query(query);

        selectedTestType = edaoTest.Test_Type__c;

        if(edaoTest.Issue_Status__c == 'Submitted' || 
           edaoTest.Issue_Status__c == 'Under Review' || 
           edaoTest.Issue_Status__c == 'IMP to be worked'){

        readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test_Name__c',false);
        }
       else if(edaoTest.Issue_Status__c == 'Test Complete'){

                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Actual_Hours__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Issue_Status__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Validation_Status__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestsonValidationStatus__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Tests_on_Withdrawn_Status__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_2__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_3__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_4__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_5__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Estimated_Start_Date__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Estimated_Completion_Date__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Other_Type_of_Service__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Ent_Test_Hrs__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Validation_Status__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Withdraw_the_Test__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('What_Test_is_Testing_this__c',true);
        readOnlyFieldsMap.put('What_Business_Unit_is_Testing_this__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestsonIssueStatus__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Type_of_Works_Performed__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Withdraw_the_Test__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test_Learn_Phase__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('EBS_Priority__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Planned_or_unplanned__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Link_to_previous_Test__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Total_Hrs__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Testected_Hours__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Actual_Hours_History__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestsonIssueStatus__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Testected_Hours_History__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Initiated_Date__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('In_Progress__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('In_Validation__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Validation_Completed_on__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Completed__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Withdrawn__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('On_Hold__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestInitiated__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestInQueue__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestValidating__c',true);
                readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestWorking__c',true);
        }
        else
        {

            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test_Name__c',false);
        }

        if(edaoTest.Issue_Status__c=='On Hold' 
                ||edaoTest.Issue_Status__c=='Withdrawn'){               
         readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Link_to_previous_Test__c',true);
         readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test__c',true);
        }
        else
        {
           readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Validation_Status__c',true);
        }

        if(edaoTest.Issue_Status__c != 'Test Complete' && relatedListFlag == 
           False){

            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Actual_Hours__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Issue_Status__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Validation_Status__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestsonValidationStatus__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Tests_on_Withdrawn_Status__c',false);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_2__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_3__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_4__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('IMP_Test_5__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Estimated_Start_Date__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Estimated_Completion_Date__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Other_Type_of_Service__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Ent_Test_Hrs__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Validation_Status__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Withdraw_the_Test__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('What_Test_is_Testing_this__c',true);
     readOnlyFieldsMap.put('What_Business_Unit_is_Testing_this__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestsonIssueStatus__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Type_of_Works_Performed__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Withdraw_the_Test__c',false);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test_Learn_Phase__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('EBS_Priority__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Planned_or_unplanned__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Link_to_previous_Test__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Total_Hrs__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Testected_Hours__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Actual_Hours_History__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestsonIssueStatus__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Testected_Hours_History__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Initiated_Date__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('In_Progress__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('In_Validation__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Validation_Completed_on__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Completed__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Withdrawn__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('On_Hold__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestInitiated__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestInQueue__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestValidating__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('TestWorking__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Description__c',true);
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test_Name__c',true);  
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('What_is_the_Business_Benefit__c',true);  
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Priority__c',true);    
            readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Document_Link__c',true);  
        } 

        readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Test_Type__c',true);
        readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Opt_in_for_Email_notification__c',true);
        readOnlyFieldsMap.put('Tests_History__c',true);
    }
```

Thanks,
Anish

Comment: Please take the pain to format your code and also explain the exact issue and the options that you have tried so far.

Comment: @Anish, Are you able to include what you have tried so far? Where are you stuck? This forum is not a free coding service. Please take a moment to read [Ask] and take the [tour]. Once you have done so, please **[edit]** your post. Thanks

Comment: Hi glls & Jigar, Please advise me how can i define test cases for test class. Rest of things i will take care..

Comment: You can learn everything you need to know by investing 45 minutes of your own time working through this [Apex Testing](https://trailhead.salesforce.com/modules/apex_testing) module.

Answer (score 0):

Not a direct answer to your question, but sometimes re-organising code to make it more testable is worthwhile. One of the benefits of writing tests is that in general it forces the code under test to be [written more cleanly](https://blog.agilistic.nl/how-writing-unit-tests-force-you-to-write-good-code-and-6-bad-arguments-why-you-shouldnt/).

Long methods are hard to understand and so to maintain. They are best broken out into pieces at various levels of abstraction. A useful technique is to separate out the data part. For your code that might be something like this:

```
@TestVisible
private static SObjectField[] COMPLETE_FIELDS = new SObjectField[] {
     Test_Tool__c.Actual_Hours__c,
     Test_Tool__c.Issue_Status__c,
     Test_Tool__c.Validation_Status__c,
     ...
}

    ...
    } else if(edaoTest.Issue_Status__c == 'Test Complete') {
        addFieldsToMap(readOnlyFieldsMap, COMPLETE_FIELDS);
    }
    ...

private static void addFieldsToMap(Map<String, Boolean> m,, SObjectField[] fields) {
    for (SObjectField f : fields) m.put(String.valueOf(f), true);
}
```